# POCO and MVC 4 Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, poco

I've just created my first MVC project.  My question is with MVC is it common practice to create POCO classes or just create the objects in the Models ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on complexity of your domain(business) logic.

Although it is not "by the book" you can use POCO classes as Models for Views.

I *personally* would split them, at least created lowest common dominator as an interface

Answer (score 1):

Totaly agree with Dejan Dakić. I will try to give a little bit extended answer.

If you have the `one-layer` solution with little amount of bussines logic, then it definetly will be faster to combine POCO object and Models in mvc. This will help you to make the little application many time faster then dividing the POCO and Model classes.

But If you have huge solution with extended architecture then you should make POCO object and models separately. Because letting know your `Presentation layer` about the objects in your `Data Access Layer` is bad move. `DAL` and `Presentation layer` should be divided with the `Business Layer`. "By the book", `Presentation Layer` know about the `Business layer`, `Business layer` knows about `Data access Layer`. And everybody knows about the `Common layer` (if you have such a layer). POCO object should belong to `Data Access Layer` but mvc Models should belong to `Presentation layer`.

Hope it helps.